# GetLastError returns 6 after call to WinHttpOpenRequest

Tags: c++, winhttp, winhttprequest, getlasterror

Im not sure if this is lack of knowledge in msdn or not. i Have the following code:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <WinHttp.h>
    #include "myHTTP.h"
int main(){
    WinHTTP newHTTP("test", "test");
        bool myResult;

        newHTTP.httpConnect(L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36",
        L"https://pages.awscloud.com/awsomedayonlineconference-reg.html",
        1,
        L"GET");

        newHTTP.httpAddHeader(L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        newHTTP.httpSend();
        myResult = newHTTP.httpReceive();



        newHTTP.closeHandles();
 return 0;
}
```

I have a class for this and the following line is being executed:
// open the request - not connected at this point

```
hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, protocol.c_str(), NULL, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 0);

if (!hRequest) {
    printf("error2: %d", GetLastError());
}
```

SO basically when i run my software, it returns here because !hrequest is empty when calling winhttpopenrequest. I have added getlasterror to see why this is but the only output i get is:

```
error2: 6
```

I then read the msdn for winhttp and i can see the errors returned from the function here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384099(v=vs.85).aspx but this mysterious error 6 is making no sense to me.

Any help on seeing why the handle is invalid?

full class code:

```
#pragma once
// WinHTTP wrapper for web protocol -- windows 8.1+
class WinHTTP {

private:
    std::string siteUsername, sitePassword;
    std::wstring UA, URL;
    bool bResult = false;
    DWORD dwSize = sizeof(DWORD); // used to handle reading data in bytes
    LPSTR pszOutBuffer; // used to Allocate space for the buffer.
    DWORD dwDownloaded = 0; // set to null if using asynchronously and use in callback function only
    HINTERNET hSession = NULL, hConnect = NULL, hRequest = NULL;

public:
    WinHTTP(std::string myuser = "", std::string mypass = "") {
        siteUsername = myuser;
        sitePassword = mypass;
    }

    // TODO: update to be able to add proxy details either here or before. do check if proxy has been detected in here and open/connect accordingly 
    void httpConnect(std::wstring userAgent, std::wstring myURL, int isHTTPS, std::wstring protocol) {

        UA = userAgent;
        URL = myURL;

        std::wstring acceptTypes = L"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";

        int portToUse;
        if (isHTTPS == 1) {
            portToUse = 443;
        }
        else {
            portToUse = 80;
        }

        //initialize http and return session handle -- use c_str to convert wstring to LPCWSTR
        hSession = WinHttpOpen(UA.c_str(),
            WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

        //make the connection request
        if (hSession) {
            hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, URL.c_str(), portToUse, 0);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "winhttpconnect error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
        }

        // open the request - not connected at this point
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, protocol.c_str(), NULL, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 0);

        if (!hRequest) {
            std::cout << "winhttpopenrequest error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
        }

    }

    std::string GetLastErrorAsString()
    {
        //Get the error message, if any.
        DWORD errorMessageID = ::GetLastError();
        if (errorMessageID == 0)
            return std::string(); //No error message has been recorded

        LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
        size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL, errorMessageID, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

        std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

        //Free the buffer.
        LocalFree(messageBuffer);

        return message;
    }

    void httpAddHeader(std::wstring myheader) {

        if (hRequest) {
            bResult = WinHttpAddRequestHeaders(hRequest, myheader.c_str(), (ULONG)-1L, WINHTTP_ADDREQ_FLAG_ADD);
        }

    }

    bool httpSend() {
        if (hRequest) {
            bResult = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        if (!bResult) {
            std::cout << "winhttpsendrequest error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    bool httpReceive() {

        if (bResult) {
            bResult = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL);
        }

        if (bResult) {

            do
            {
                // Check for available data.
                dwSize = 0; //query data available looks for data in bytes
                if (!WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize))
                {
                    std::cout << "WinHttpQueryDataAvailable error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
                    break;
                }

                // No more available data.
                if (!dwSize)
                    return false;

                // Allocate space for the buffer. as dwSize now holds the size of the request
                pszOutBuffer = new char[dwSize + 1];  // just a way of freeing up memory 
                if (!pszOutBuffer)
                {
                    printf("Out of memory\n"); // couldnt allocate enough
                    return false;
                }

                ZeroMemory(pszOutBuffer, dwSize + 1); // fills a block of memory with 0s

                                                      // we know the expect size and have the pszoutbffer to write to - read the Data.
                if (!WinHttpReadData(hRequest, (LPVOID)pszOutBuffer,
                    dwSize, &dwDownloaded))
                {
                        std::cout << "WinHttpReadData error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%s", pszOutBuffer);
                }

                // Free the memory allocated to the buffer.
                delete[] pszOutBuffer;
                return true;

                // This condition should never be reached since WinHttpQueryDataAvailable
                // reported that there are bits to read.
                if (!dwDownloaded)
                    return false;

            } while (dwSize > 0);

        }

        return false;

    }

    void closeHandles() {
        if (hRequest) WinHttpCloseHandle(hRequest);
        if (hConnect) WinHttpCloseHandle(hConnect);
        if (hSession) WinHttpCloseHandle(hSession);
    }

};
```

Comment: Is `hConnect` valid?

Comment: `GetLastError` returns a `DWORD`, so 6 is a correct value.
Error code
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx

Example usage,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384091(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @SombreroChicken thanks, see update question, any reason why hconnect would be invalid?

Comment: We can't tell you that. You need to check the `hConnect` and `GetLastError()` after `WinHttpConnect`, the same way you do after `WinHttpOpen` and after `WinHttpOpenRequest`.

Comment: it is not generating any errors as you can see on my code otherwise it would have said @MaxVollmer

Comment: *"as you can see on my code"* I see in your code that you do not check for errors after calling `WinHttpConnect`.

Comment: @MaxVollmer sorry i added it after, but again its returning nothing, its empty.

Comment: I can only comment on the code you show us.

Comment: @MaxVollmer im litterely telling you i added the code from your answer. it is returning no errors

Comment: I compiled and ran your code here: after this line `hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, URL.c_str(), portToUse, 0);`, `hConnect` contains `NULL`, and `GetLastError()` returns 12005 which is `Invalid URL`

Comment: @Jabberwocky but this doesnt make sense, why would the url be invalid?

Comment: @jimmy _why would it be invalid?_ Good question, I don't know and I don't have time to search any further now, but that's what is actually happening here.

Comment: @Jabberwocky figured it out, its because the url should not contain http://

Comment: @jimmy you should answer your own question.

Comment: `WinHttpConnect` expects a servername, not a URL. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why you get error code 6**

Error code 6 is the [System Error Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx) `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`.

It tells you that the `hConnect` you pass into `WinHttpOpenRequest` is invalid.

You only check `hSession` after your call to `WinHttpOpen`, and `hRequest` after your call to `WinHttpOpenRequest`. But you never check if `hConnect` is valid.

You need to check the `hConnect` returned by `WinHttpConnect` as well, and if it's invalid check `GetLastError()` before calling another WINAPI method:

```
hSession = WinHttpOpen(UA.c_str(), WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_NO_PROXY, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME, WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS, 0);

if (hSession) {
    hConnect = WinHttpConnect(hSession, URL.c_str(), portToUse, 0);

    if (hConnect) {
        hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, protocol.c_str(), NULL, NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 0);

        if (!hRequest) {
            std::cout << "WinHttpOpenRequest error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "WinHttpConnect error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
    }
}
else {
    std::cout << "WinHttpOpen error " << GetLastErrorAsString();
}
```

**Why your call to `WinHttpConnect` fails**

The [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384091(v=vs.85).aspx) tell us that `WinHttpConnect` expects a *server name*, not a URL:

> *pswzServerName [in]*
>
>   Pointer to a null-terminated string that contains the host name of an
>   HTTP server. Alternately, the string can contain the IP address of the
>   site in ASCII, for example, 10.0.1.45.

However the string you provide contains a URL, which is not valid. You need to change `"https://pages.awscloud.com/awsomedayonlineconference-reg.html"` to `"pages.awscloud.com"`, and then provide the path to the page as parameter in `WinHttpOpenRequest`:

```
hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnect, protocol.c_str(), path.c_str(), NULL, WINHTTP_NO_REFERER, WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES, 0);
```

where `path` is a string containing `"/awsomedayonlineconference-reg.html"`.

You could split your URL into parts for this, or change your `httpConnect` method to get servername and path as separate parameters.

Comment: ive just updated the question with full code, any reason why hconnect would be invalid?

Comment: it is returning nothing on the winhttpconnect error. that is why im confused, means no errors right?

Comment: @jimmy *why hconnect would be invalid* A good starting point for figuring it out would be a call to GetLastError. We can't make it for you.

Comment: i have called getlasterror @n.m. but it is empty, no errors.